# Repeating an attribute value in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, max

I have a simple query that I would like some specific results but not sure of the right way to go about it.  I'm using a SQL Server database and my query is as follows:

```
SELECT  dt.year ,
        db.dist_code ,
        db.dist_name ,
        db.s_code ,
        db.s_name ,
        fl.zip ,
        fl.num_births ,

        total_enrollment 
FROM    dbo.fact_enrollment_school AS fs
        INNER JOIN dbo.dim_building AS db ON fs.building_key = db.building_key
        INNER JOIN dbo.dim_time AS dt ON fs.time_key = dt.time_key
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.fact_live_birth AS fl ON dt.time_key = fl.time_key
                                                AND db.building_key = fl.building_key

GROUP BY dt.year ,
        db.dist_code ,
        db.dist_name ,
        db.school_code ,
        db.school_name ,
        fl.zip ,
        total_enrollment ,
        fl.num_births
```

[image]

What I need is to output the num_births total for every district_code that is the same.

Desired output:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can achieve this by window function:

```
SELECT  dt.year ,
    db.dist_code ,
    db.dist_name ,
    db.s_code ,
    db.s_name ,
    fl.zip ,
    sum(fl.num_births) over (partition by dt.year, db.dist_code),

    total_enrollment 
FROM    dbo.fact_enrollment_school AS fs
    INNER JOIN dbo.dim_building AS db ON fs.building_key = db.building_key
    INNER JOIN dbo.dim_time AS dt ON fs.time_key = dt.time_key
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.fact_live_birth AS fl ON dt.time_key = fl.time_key
                                            AND db.building_key = fl.building_key;
```

Comment: the above is close to what im looking for but im working with multiple years with each year having a different max number for num_births (example: 2007 num_births = 56, 2008 num_births = 70).  When summing the total num_births it sums up the total from 5 years giving me an incorrect result.

Comment: edited the answer..does it work for you?? u can add multiple partition by clause to window functions, which may result similar to what group by would in normal aggregate queries..!!

Comment: Your edited version has the correct logic but my num_births is still being summed which is producing the incorrect results.  I'm not very familiar with the over clause but can you use over without the sum?  The results for num_births shouldnt be a sum.

Comment: Hi sorry for misunderstanding your problem..can you please elaborate a bit on this .. "num_births total for every district_code that is the same" .. Aren't you asking for sum of Num_Births in a particular year and district .. understanding the problem would lead to a corrcet solution..

Comment: I added a group by and to your suggested solution and was able to return the correct results.  Thank you